# Secondary x-axis labels for sample size with ggplot2 on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, label, axis

I am trying to replicate the following graph, which I made in Excel, with ggplot2 in R:

[image: Sample]

I am able to successfully create the lines with geom_line(), the labels with geom_text() / some manual adjustments, and the y-axis. Find my code below:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

somedata <- read_excel("somedata.xlsx")
somedata[,c(3:6)] <- somedata[,c(3:6)] * 100
somedata[,6] <- somedata[,6] + 25 

somegraph <- ggplot(data = somedata, aes(x = date))
somegraph + 
  geom_point(aes(y = eligible_main), shape = 15, size = 4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = eligible_main)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = eligible_center), size = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = eligible_upper), linetype = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = eligible_lower), linetype = 2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), labels = paste0(seq(0, 100, 10), "%")) + 
  labs(title = "Title", x = "Time", y = "Percentage") + theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

For reference, here is some fake data I created in a similar format as the data I am graphing. You can paste it into R and run my code above in the console: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43876540434394267818

But I am finding it extremely difficult to **create the sample-size secondary labels on the x-axis in the same orientation**. Is there a simple solution to this in ggplot2, or with another package? Also, can I add annotation lines onto my graph to point things out once finished?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi!  Are you able to post the output of `dput(somedata)`?  Most are going to be unwilling to download data from a link provided, so that's the best way to share your data frame so we can help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution that might help.  I was unable to grab the data you shared, I created my own dummy dataset as follows:

```
set.seed(12345)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  dates=as.Date('2020-03-01')+days(0:9),
  y_vals=rnorm(10, 50,7),
  n=100
)
```

First, the basic plot:

```
library(scales)
library(ggrepel)    
p.basic <- ggplot(df, aes(dates, y_vals)) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point(size=2.5, shape=15) +
        geom_text_repel(
            aes(label=paste0(round(y_vals, 1), '%')),
            size=3, direction='y', force=7) +
        ylim(0,100) +
        scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks('day'), labels=date_format('%b %d')) +
        theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that my code is a bit different than your own.  Text labels are pushed away via the `ggrepel` package.  I'm also using some functions from `scales` to fix and set formatting of the date axis (note also `lubridate` is the package used to create the dates in the dummy dataset above).  Otherwise, pretty standard `ggplot` stuff there.

For the text outside the axis, the best way to do this is through a custom annotation, where you have to setup the grob.  The approach here is as follows:

- Move the axis "down" to allow room for the extra text.  We do that via setting a margin on top of the axis title.
- Turn off clipping via `coord_cartesian(clip='off')`.  This is needed in order to see the annotations outside of the plot by allowing things to be drawn outside the plot area.
- Loop through the values of `df$n`, to create a separate `annotation_custom` object added to the plot via a `for` loop.

Here's the code:

```
p <- p.basic +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(50,0,0,0))) +
    coord_cartesian(clip='off')

for (i in 1:length(df$n)) {
  p <- p + annotation_custom(
    textGrob(
      label=paste0('n=',df$n[i]), rot=90, gp=gpar(fontsize=9)),
      xmin=df$dates[i], xmax=df$dates[i], ymin=-25, ymax=-15
    )
}
p
```

[image]

#### Advanced Options for more Fun

Two more things to add: Annotations (like callouts for specific points + text), and the lines below the plot in between the axis label stuff.

**For lines below the axis:** You can add `breaks=` to other axes fairly easily via `scale_...` and the `breaks=` parameter; however, for a date axis, it's... complicated.  This is why we will just add lines using the same method as above for the text below the axis.  The idea here is to break the axis into `sub.div` segments in the code below, which is based on how many discrete values are in your x axis.  I could do this in-line a few times... but it's fun to create the variable first:

```
sub.div <- 1/length(df$n)
```

Then, I use that to create the lines by annotating individually the lines along the step `sub.div*i` using a `for` loop again:

```
for (i in 1:(length(df$n)-1)) {
  p <- p + annotation_custom(
    linesGrob(
      x=unit(c(sub.div*i,sub.div*i), 'npc'),
      y=unit(c(0,-0.2), 'npc')   # length of the line below axis
    )
  )
}
```

[image]

*I realize I don't have the lines on the ends here, but you can probably see how it would be easy to add that by modifying the method above.*

**Annotations (with arrows, why not?):** There are lots of ways to do annotations.  [Some are covered here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html) using the `annotate()` function.  [As well as here](https://ggplot2-book.org/annotations.html).  You can use `annotate()` if you wish, but in this example, I'm just going to use `geom_label` for the text labels and `geom_curve` to make some curvy arrows.

You can manually pass individual `aes()` values through the call to both functions for each annotation.  For example, `geom_text(aes(x=as.Date('2020-03-01'), y=55,...`, but if you have a few in your dataset, it would be advisable to set the annotations based on information within the dataframe itself.  I'll do that here first, where we will label two of the points:

```
df$notes <- c('','','','Wow!','','','OMG!!!','','','')
```

You can use the value of `df$notes` to indicate which of the points are getting labeled, and also take advantage of the mapping of `x` and `y` values within the same dataset.

Then you just need to add the two geoms to your plot, modifying as you wish to fit your own aesthetics.

```
p <- p + geom_curve(
    data=df[which(df$notes!=''),],
    mapping=aes(x=dates+0.5, xend=dates, y=y_vals+20, yend=y_vals+2),
    color='red', curvature = 0.5,
    arrow=arrow(length=unit(5,'pt'))
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data=df[which(df$notes!=''),],
    aes(y=y_vals+20, label=notes),
    size=4, color='red', hjust=0
  )
```

[image]

**Final thing: Horizontal Lines**  One final thing that I noticed in your code before, but forgot to point out is that to make your horizontal lines, just use `geom_hline`.  It's much easier.  Also, you can do it in two calls to `geom_hline` pretty easily (and even in just one call if you care to pass a dataframe to the function):

```
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = 50, size=2, color='gray30') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(25,75), linetype=2, color='gray30')
```

Just note that it's advisable to add these two `geom_hline` calls ***before*** `geom_line` or `geom_point` in the original `p.basic` plot so they are behind everything else.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution worked really well, and is conceptually straightforward.

If you have the time, would you mind also elaborating on whether this same approach would work for adding custom vertical line / text annotations? Like if I wanted to point out a data point on the graph, and note that an event occurred then.

Comment: I've added the way to make the vertical lines as well as some annotation examples to the solution.  :)

Comment: Oh, and the horizontal lines: easier to do them with `geom_hline` and with simpler code.

Comment: You are the best. I really appreciate this!